# Multimedia running very slow & weird ( In Virtualbox )

Tags: 12.04, sound, virtualbox, multimedia

i've got Ubuntu Precise ( 12.04.2 ) running via VirtualBox on Windows 7 host machine ( both 64 bit systems ) - intel i3 2350m with 4GB of RAM - 1.5 GB allocated to Virtualbox.

All multimedia played on Ubuntu is very slow and what is most disturbing - audio is played in very weird way - bassy , sound like alien :(

VirtualBox uses WindowsDirectSound ICH AC97 , 32 Megabytes of Video memory ( intel hd3000 )

any ideas how to fix it ?

--edit
Install also lubuntu 12.04 , same problem

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a common problem for many Linux guests, regardless of host operating system.

A workaround/fix was identified by someone using Ubuntu 9.04 was to stick the following into **/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf** (might need a .conf extension, or might not):

```
options snd-intel8x0 ac97_clock=48000
options snd slots=snd-intel8x0
# CvwD.FAMlirE10w6:82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller
alias snd-card-0 snd-intel8x0
```

The above worked *like a charm* (ie: I didn't analyze it very deeply, just "had faith, copy/paste") for me in Ubuntu 13.10.

The key must be setting the clock to 48000, IMHO. I'm not sure about the rest of the stuff having to do with "intel" things. That #-commented line is probably doing nothing, but who am I to question it? Maybe someone else will come along and help clarify these minor concerns.

For reference:

- [VirtualBox Forums #20254](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=20254)
- [VirtualBox Forums #4605](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4605)
- [Ubuntu Forums #1341984](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1341984)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution was posted at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/151096/sound-in-ubuntu-10-04-guest-vm-in-a-ubuntu-8-04-host-is-slow-how-to-fix-it/714887#714887), involving a **default-fragments** value.